# Must I overwrite PHP's DateTime with a DateTimeZone afterwards explicitly?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I receive a time:

```
0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
Greenwich Mean Time
```

I save this in a DateTime as:

```
$event->startTime = new DateTime($item->startTime, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
```

Which gives me:

```
  protected 'startTime' => 
    object(DateTime)[137]
      public 'date' => string '0001-01-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 2
      public 'timezone' => string 'Z' (length=1)
```

Which means it ignores the timezone. From the docs:

> Note:
>
> The $timezone parameter and the
>   current timezone are ignored when the
>   $time parameter either is a UNIX
>   timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or
>   specifies a timezone (e.g.
>   2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

If I override it afterwards:

```
$event->startTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
```

I get:

```
  protected 'startTime' => 
    object(DateTime)[137]
      public 'date' => string '0001-01-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

So, the response says the timezone must be GMT/UCT which is +0, but PHP decides **tl; dr** and I end up with my default php.ini timezone of +2. Isn't that wrong?

Anyway, I will use the starting time as a countdown, so the timezone is crucial. My question is: is it correct for me to overwrite the timezone to UCT? Will that give me the correct time when I am going to use DateTime::diff?

Comment: Seeing as PHP is a server-side language, getting the Datetime object is always gonna end up being the time from the server, no?

Comment: True, but must I persist the DateTime with the event's timezone or with the server's timezone?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) says that you should not use `GMT` as a valid timezone for the DateTimeZone class.

It might be possible to drop the `Z` and specify the timezone when creating the DateTime, so the constructor does not ignore the timezone.

```
$startTime = new DateTime('0001-01-01T00:00:00.000', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

It would be easiest to persist everything as UTC, otherwise running the code in different timezones or when daylight savings is in affect *could* potentially cause unforseen issues.